# Help with Tikz Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I need help to draw this graph using tikz.

[image]

Comment: What you try so far? Does text in nodes should be so colorful?

Answer (score 4):

Since incidentally I have a some spare time and solution using `forest` package is quite simple ...
but in feature please show us what you try so far and where you stuck in your effort!

```
\documentclass[border=3.131592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand\A{\textcolor{purple}{A}}
\newcommand\B{\textcolor{red}{B}}
\newcommand\C{\textcolor{teal}{C}}
\newcommand\D{\textcolor{olive}{D}}
\newcommand\E{\textcolor{cyan}{E}}
\newcommand\F{\textcolor{purple}{F}}
\newcommand\G{\textcolor{purple}{G}}
\renewcommand\H{\textcolor{orange}{H}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes 
    circle, minimum size=2.8em, inner sep=0pt, draw,
% tree
    edge = {thick, double},
    s sep=5mm,
    l sep=5mm
          },
% tree body
[\B\C\E
    [\B\C\E
        [\B\C\E
            [\B\E\G
                [\B\F\G]
                [\E\G\H]
            ]
        ]
        [\B\C\E
            [\C\D\E]
        ]
    ]
    [~,phantom,fit=band]
    [\B\C
        [\A\B\C]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]